# Dataset visualization

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, weka

I am using weka for traffic classification. I have an .arff dataset that contains different columns and rows. Each row is an instance where each column is a feature. Is there any software that can visualize my Dataset for more than two features?

I have noticed that weka can visualize two dataset,However I need to visualize up to 8 features.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the so called [Parallel Coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_coordinates) which can visualize any number of features. There are many existing implementations, some of which are avaliable from [prof. Inselberg page](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~aiisreal/)